How to disable monitor on boot using xorg.conf?
I have an always-connected monitor using the HDMI-1-0 port, and I want to set the default xrandr value to xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --off on Linux boot. Even when I add this to my .xinitrc, the monitor turns on at startup. Additionally, when I enable it using the Win+P shortcut, the display dimensions are not as they were the last time.
I decided to write a config file in xorg.conf.d/30-disable-hdmi.conf as follows:
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1-0"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection

However, with this config, I cannot reactivate the monitor without changing the Ignore option to false and restarting display-manager.service.
I also tried other configurations like this:
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1-0"
    Option "Primary" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1-0"
    Option "Primary" "false"
    Option "Enable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "eDP-1"
    Option "Primary" "true"
    Option "Enable" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1-0"
    Option "Primary" "false"
    Option "Enable" "false"
EndSection

But none of these configurations worked. How can I achieve this?
Here is my monitor.xml file:
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>2560</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>2</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1-0</connector>
          <vendor>SAM</vendor>
          <product>LC32G5xT</product>
          <serial>HK2W300061</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>3840</width>
          <height>2160</height>
          <rate>59.940</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>2</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>NE180QDM-NZ2</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1600</height>
          <rate>60.002</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>

I am currently on Ubuntu 24.04.
